# How to create wrapping menu tabs with CSS in Omega

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the menu api (MENU_LOCAL_TASK) to create tabs in Drupal 7. In [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega), I can't figure out how to wrap the tabs in css so that they are responsive. I'm new to Omega. This was easily accomplished in other themes.

Comment: What do you mean 'wrap the tabs in CSS'?  Do you mean that you need to add classes to each tab?  On another note, you might want to work on your [acceptance rate](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) to get answers more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the default system.menus.css in Drupal sets the white-space property to:

- white-space: nowrap;

The default value for white-space is normal.  So, if you set the white-space property on your menu's UL to white-space:normal they will wrap when your screen size gets smaller.

I placed the following in my global.css.

- ul.primary {white-space: normal; }